# Music video where a car drops into the frame and slams into the ground behind the singer

Tags: music-video

I remember liking a music video in the 80s or 90s, but all I can remember is the first few seconds of the video.  The singer is standing in the center of the frame and a car falls from above the frame and smashes on the ground behind the singer.  He doesn't flinch and I think it is a double-exposure camera trick.

Comment: That imagery is used in the movie "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind." Beck and Jon Brion did the soundtrack, but as far as I know, there was no music video that accompanied it.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)